# Open source multi region, consistent at-least-once FIFO solution: Dedicated Queue (e.g. Kafka) vs Database (e.g. Cassandra, RethinkDB)?

Tags: apache-kafka, cassandra, confluent-platform, rethinkdb

I've been searching for a FIFO solution where producers and consumers can be deployed in multiple data-centers, in different regions (e.g. >20ms ping). Obviously paying the price of increased latency, the main goal is to handle transparently the increased latency, spikes in latency, link failures.

This theoretical use-case is like this:

```
Super Fast Producer --sticky-load-balancing-with-fail-over--> Multi-Region Processors --> 
       Queue(FIFO based on order established by the producer) --> Multi-Region Consumers with fail-over
```

Consumers should not consume from the same "queue" at the same time, however, let's not consider the scaling aspect here. If the replication and fail-over work well for one "queue" the partitioning can be applied even at the application level with a decent amount of effort.

Thoughts:

- In order for fail-over to work correctly, the Queue (e.g. messages, consumer offsets) must be active-active synchronously replicated between data centers. I don't see how an active-standby asynchronous topology can work without losing messages or break FIFO in failure scenarios.
- Kafka stretch cluster would be perfect, although it can span multiple availability zones (<2ms ping and stable connections), most people advise against multiple regions (>15ms ping, unstable connections).

  - Confluent Platform 5.4 with the synchronous replication feature is in Preview, we could fail-over consumers at the application level in case the local cluster is down. Since data is replicated synchronously we should not break FIFO or lose messages during fail-over. In order to ensure a more active-active setup, we could rotate the Consumers periodically between data centers (e.g. once or twice a day in off-peak hours).
- A DB (like Cassandra) can handle consistency across multiple data-center/regions. However, a queue use-case is an anti-pattern ([Using Cassandra as a Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35684802/using-cassandra-as-a-queue)).

  - The first point would be about the pure insert/delete workload which will make the DB work really hard to remove tombstones. It is sub-optimal use of the DB, but if it can handle the workload reliably than it is not a problem IMHO
  - The second point is about polling, consumers will generate a large amount of quorum reads just for polling the DB even if there is no data. Again IMHO Cassandra will handle this reliably even if it is a poor use of its capabilities.
- Using a DB with notifications, like CouchDB/RethinkDB. CouchDB's replication is asynchronous so I do not see how Consumers can have a consistent view of the queue. For RethinkDB I am not sure how reliable it works across regions with `majority` reads and writes.

Have you deployed such "queues" in production, which would you choose?

Answer (score 1):

Kafka supports 2 patterns Publish-Subscribe and Message Queue. There are some places discussed the differences. [here](https://streaml.io/resources/tutorials/concepts/messaging-and-queuing)

The problem you stated can be solved using Kafka. The FIFO queue can be implemented using the topic/partition/key message. All messages with the same key will belong to the same partition hence we can achieve the FIFO attribute. In case you want to increase the consuming throughput, you just need to increase the total of partitions per topic and increase number of consumers.

Other queues such as RabbitMQ are not easy, though. For load balancing the workload, we must use the separate queue which increasing the management cost.

You can implement many kinds of delivery semantics such as at-most-once, at-least-once, exactly-once (literally) at the producer side and the consumer side. Kafka also supports multi-center deployments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, one Kafka cluster with Consumer Groups would be ideal. If the data centers are relatively close to each-other then a Kafka stretched cluster can be deployed spanning them. But if you have >20ms ping and spikes/failures it is not advisable: https://www.confluent.io/blog/multi-region-data-replication, https://www.altoros.com/blog/multi-cluster-deployment-options-for-apache-kafka-pros-and-cons/, https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Design-and-Deployment-Considerations-for-High-Availability/ta-p/248188

Comment: Agreed that there are some issues related to the Kafka cluster deployed across regions. Maintaining high availability and consistency across is hard across multiple regions. Cassandra's replication is more dynamic in this.

Answer (score 0):

---

Cassandra is not designed for queue modeling, and as you said using Cassandra as a queue is an anti-pattern. It can turn quick into a nightmare.

The main problem with the queue is the deletes (Cassandra doesn't perform well for frequently updated data anyway).

Here is a link that might help you understanding delete/queue. 
https://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/10/20/domain-modeling-around-deletes-or-using-cassandra-as-a-queue-even-when-you-know-better/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've read this article some time ago. The idea is that Cassandra can support huge write throughput, the throughput for this use case is very far from what Cassandra can do. I care more about the consistency Cassandra can deliver across distant data-centers, even if the performance is very far from optimal. I am currently interested more in the end to end reliability than throughput.

Comment: You are welcome, for me your use case is closer to Kafka than Cassandra

Comment: if you have personally seen the "nightmare" you mentioned, please share what were the problems faced, in fact this is what I am most interested in, real world deployments of similar multi-region "queues" and real world "horror stories" :)